# How to retain/recall values of tableLayoutPanel of child form from main form button in C#(Visual Studio) 2010?

Tags: c#

I have 2 questions and need your guidance

1) Please guide me as how to retain/recall textboxes values of tablelayoutpanel of child form from the button click event of parent form in C#.,
Scenario is that , I have filled out the values in textboxes of tablelayoutpanel in child form and then return to parent form . What if i want to see/review the values of (previously) filled textboxes values of tablelayoutpanel of child form, can i do that? Please suggest me a solution.,

2)Can i redraw rows/columns of tablelayoutpanel dynamically upon changing user input(of rows/columns) . Please be remember in this case i need to discard the previous one and redraw the tablelayoutpanel all over again.Please suggest how to discard the previous one?

Thanks and Regards,
Asad

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566/best-way-to-access-a-control-on-another-form-in-winforms) may help you partially towards resolving query one.

For the second query, you can perhaps override the OnPaint event but that might mean custom drawing *all* your controls on the form, which could be a herculean task depending on how many other controls are present.