# call a button of different form in c# Forms?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, button

I am new to C#, I am creating a application in which there is a need of using two forms
one is `Mainform` and other is `DialogForm`.

The `DialogForm` has two buttons `btnYes` and `btnNo`.

whenever the user clicks the close button, `FormClosing` Event invokes in which I am calling the `DialogForm` as shown below:

```
DialogForm ex = new DialogForm();
ex.ShowDialog(this);
```

Now I want to give `e.cancel=false` for `btnYes` and `e.cancel=true` for `btnNo`. (this explained by my sir, only basics)

I know how to give functions to a `Button` which is in same `Form` but I dont know how to if the `Form` is different.

I have gone through some [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566/best-way-to-access-a-control-on-another-form-in-winforms) but as I am new to c#, I can't understand it.
If you atleast provide me some links that would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms have a property `DialogResult`. You can set it in the button event handlers.

```
DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
// or
DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
```

Then you can call the form like this

```
if (ex.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.Yes) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

---

You can also set the `CancelButton` property of the form in the properties window. Microsoft says:

> Gets or sets the button control that is clicked when the user presses the ESC key.

The form has also an `AcceptButton` property. Microsoft says:

> Gets or sets the button on the form that is clicked when the user presses the ENTER key.

Comment: Yeah its working. But is there any other way to call a other form button. I mean using `instance` or anything else? please give any link , i dont want to waste your time @Olivier Jacot-Descombes

Comment: You can make the button click event handler public and call it from elsewhere. `public void btn_(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }`. `otherform.btn_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);`. If you want to close another form, just call `otherform.Close();`. And, of cause, you can always create your own public methods in a form. E.g. `public void ClearAllFields() { ... }`.