# Reload combobox items from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms, I want to reload combobox items in Form1 from Form2.
I set Form1 as MdiParent of Form2 like this:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.MdiParent = this;
f2.Show();
```

How can I access Form1 controls from within Form2?

Comment: in form2 class : `((Form1)this.MdiParent).Combobox`

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566/best-way-to-access-a-control-on-another-form-in-winforms

Comment: @defaultlocale that question hasn't any acceptable answer

Comment: @Ehsan Question itself and it's top answers provide useful suggestions.

Comment: @Ehsan I would like you to plz accept the answer you found the best that alongwith the answerer will also increase your reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
String nameComboBox = "nameComboBoxForm1"; //name of combobox in form1
ComboBox comboBoxForm1 = (ComboBox)f2.MdiParent.FindControl(nameComboBox);
```

Answer (score 1):

on `Form1` you need to define a property like this:

```
Public ComboBox.ObjectCollection MyComboboxitems{
    get{ return {the Combox's name}.Items}
}
```

Then on `Form2` in the `Load` event handler:

```
{name of form2 combobox}.Items = ((Form1)Me.MdiParent).MyComboboxitems;
```

This is to not expose all the properties of the combobox on form one, just the one you want.

In the code examples replace {...} with the actual object names.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a public static List in Form1 and set it to the datasource of form1combobox as shown here.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;
    }
    public static List<string> list;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.MdiParent = this;
        frm2.Show();
        comboBox11.DataSource = list;
    }
}
```

In the load event of form2, set the declared form1 list to refer to new instantiated list having the items of form2.combobox.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    List<string> list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        comboBox1.DataSource = list;
        Form1.list = list;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Form1 f1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)f1.Controls["comboBox1"];
cb.Items.Clear();
cb.Items.Add("Testing1");
cb.Items.Add("Testing2");
```