# access application's Form elements from another class?

Tags: c#

I have c# project in which i have form and i want to access elements from that form from another class, how I can do this?

I tried `Form1 f1 = new Form1();`
and then `f1.pictureBox` but it's not correct, 
I have exception for `Form1 f1 = new Form1();` saying:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in MMS-Lab1.exe
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to access a control on another form in Windows Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566/best-way-to-access-a-control-on-another-form-in-windows-forms)

Comment: Assuming `pictureBox` is public, that's fine - it won't cause a Stack Overflow.  Where is your call to `new Form1()` - is it inside `Form1`'s constructor by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Call new Form1() is in another class called Controller before Controller's constructor. 
Stack overflow is caused by Form1 f1 = new Form1(), why is that?