# Change form control property outside of form class

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I change control properties outside of the main form class?

I have a function that takes a form object as a parameter

```
public MyFunc(Form f)
{
    // I want to do something like this
    f.lblMylabel.txt = "foo"
}
```

How do I reference the forms controls and change property values?

Comment: This should work (apart from the obvious syntax errors), Is your label set as private? It would be much better to make a method on your form to do this also

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to access a control on another form in Windows Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566/best-way-to-access-a-control-on-another-form-in-windows-forms)

Comment: If I create control by dragging it onto form in designer, where do I set the accessibility to public?

Answer (score 0):

When you open a form in your mdi parent form, set that form object public and then get it by the reference of mdi parent class.